# TableView header contents not visible to UI Automation

Tags: ios, xcode, automation

I would like to use UI Automation to automate testing on a game app. The main window has an embedded TableView with a header and footer. The footer has a single button and this is visible to UI Automation. But the header has a number of buttons and labels that are enabled and changed as the game progresses. But apart from the header name, none of these elements are visible to UI Automation.

Both are loaded from Nibs by code like this:

```
- (UIView *) gameHeader
{
  if (!gameHeader)
  {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"GameHeader" owner: self options: nil];
  }

  return gameHeader;
```

}

In the .xib files, the View and the buttons etc have accessibility enabled and each has an identifier specified.

Using the Accessibility Inspector results in the same lack of visibility.

At the same time, other windows with embedded tableViews and less complex headers are displaying the internal components.

Any ideas as the what the problem is?

Thanks

Comment: do you set the header to have an accessibility name/id?

Comment: Yes, it is set in the .xib files along with names for all the components. But to UI Automation only the top level name is exposed and none of the components.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am facing the same issue.